# Thematic, genred concepts in Ancient Greek?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, pronunciation

Trying to come up with magical 'schools' for a game, and my goal is to:

1. Use Ancient Greek, Koine if absolutely necessary
2. Have words of generally the same length and number of syllables (not like, seven four-letter words and one fourteen-letter word)
3. Have a Romanized form that is somewhat intuitive to pronounce (not like the Latin 'uu')
4. Be categories of the same 'thing' at the same level of specificity. (Not 'air, water, diamond, fire' or 'mind, soul, feet')

With that said, my attempt is:

- Hule - Matter
- Kinesis - Force
- Chronos - Time
- Topos - Space
- Nous - Mind
- Pneuma - Spirit
- Pathos - Emotion
- Telos - Purpose
- Moira - Fate
- Dunamis - Potential

Do these 'go' together in tense/theme/level of specificity? If not, can you suggest better words/conjugations that fit the above goals?

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only person here who is creating a game, although I've been using Latin rather than Greek, and the concept of "magic" is different. :)

Comment: Latin and pseudo-Latin (Harry Potter) have been done quite a bit in pop culture. Good luck to you!

Comment: Very true! I thought it might work to my advantage in that there's more general familiarity with it. Truth be told, though, I would have chosen it either way. Good luck to you as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of your translations look good to me! Some of these words have other common meanings, like *hylē* meaning "forest", but these are reasonable technical terms that I wouldn't be surprised to find in Aristotle or the like.

However, if you're going for the Ancient Greek aesthetic, I'd use the letter *y* instead of *u* for hypsilon when it's not part of a diphthong. At the height of the classical period, hypsilon on its own was pronounced `/y/` (a front rounded vowel), so the Romans borrowed the symbol *Y* to represent it, and the convention stuck.

Similarly, I'd borrow a trick from J.R.R. Tolkien, who observed that English-speakers always mispronounce foreign words ending in an *e*. So whenever a non-English name ended in *e*, he would write it with a diaeresis *ë*. This didn't really mean anything linguistically, but it made English-speakers much more likely to pronounce the final vowel.

(Another option is to write ēta as *ē* and ōmega as *ō* everywhere, which for your purposes will only affect *hylē* and *kinēsis*. But that's a bit harder to type for most people.)

Comment: Another option which would have the same effect *and* corresponds to common transcription standards would be to write "hylē." In the OP's list that is the only vowel that would use the macron. EDIT: actually it should also be "kinēsis."

Comment: @brianpck Good point! Added a note

Comment: If you want to avoid characters that may be more challenging to type, you could spell the _e_ phonetically, e.g. _hyleh_ (or whatever spelling most closely matches the general sound). Is this a game where someone playing the game will hear these spoken to them, like in a video game, or something more like a table-top game where they'll read it and say it without being exposed to the sounds first?

Comment: @Adam True, I have used Vh to indicate long vowels before, and it's unambiguous in Greek (where `/h/` only occurs word-initially and arguably after voiceless stops). But forms like "Kinehsis" and "Sohcrates" take some getting used to.

Comment: @Adam I haven't decided which the player will be exposed to first. At the same time, I can't decide which is better: using non-keyboard characters like ē or making them look less elegant but more readable via y's, h's or double-vowels.

Comment: @Hugh True! But I hesitate to suggest that here because the pitch accent is on the first syllable in _hýlē_.

Comment: Good point; I'll delete my suggestion for É and é for macron.

Comment: @Carduus You could include glossary that has a pronunciation guide, although that might not be feasible if this is a computer/mobile/console game. Now that I think about it, even if a player reads it one way for a while, once they hear multiple NPCs pronounce it a specific way they'll alter their own pronunciation to match.